# I can't get java to recognize my resource bundle?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, localization

I'm new to Java (and coding in general) and I am trying to understand how to work with localization, but I am running into a problem when just following along with tutorials.... My bundles aren't being found.

here is my main

```java
package com.company;

import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        

        Locale eng = new Locale("en" );
        Locale fre = new Locale("fr");
        Locale span = new Locale("es");

        ResourceBundle englishBundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle("myBundle", eng);
        ResourceBundle frenchBundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle("myBundle", fre);
        ResourceBundle spanishBundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle("myBundle", span);
        System.out.println(englishBundle.getString("hello"));
        System.out.println(frenchBundle.getString("hello"));
        System.out.println(spanishBundle.getString("hello"));
    }
}
```

I created the bundle using intelliJ create Resource Bundle which gave me 4 files.

- `myBundle.properties`
- `myBundle_en.properties`
- `myBundle_es.properties`
- `myBundle_fr.properties`

Each file has a single translation hello

When I run the code I get the following exception: `MissingResourceException: cant find bundle for base name myBundle`

Comment: Where are the files of your resource bundle located?

Comment: they are in the same package as my Main. <br /> com/myBundle.properties
com/myBundle_en.properties
com/myBundle_es.properties
com/myBundle_fr.properties

Comment: Can you try moving them in a resource root (directly in the resources folder, no package)?

Comment: You mean to move them up to the src folder?  they are currently all marked as subfiles of "Resource Bundle 'myBundle'"

Comment: If you don't have a resource folder, yes

Comment: ResourceBundle names are a lot like fully qualified class names.  If you have `com/myBundle.properties`, then your code needs to use `ResourceBundle.getBundle("com.myBundle")`.

Comment: Thanks dan1st and @VGR .  Both of these comments solved the problem, if you put them in the answers area I will upvote them!

Comment: Thanks @dan1st and VGR . Both of these comments solved the problem, if you put them in the answers area I will upvote them